# Line with varying gradient in canvas

Tags: android, canvas

I need to draw a line with a varying gradient in a canvas. Any idea how to do this? I have done a lot of search and have not been able to find any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `setShader()` method on your `Paint` object to set it to a gradient (likely a `LinearGradient`, but there are a handful of things you can use. Check the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setShader%28android.graphics.Shader%29)). Then draw away!